# input 100% в ие7

Tags: html

Тема конечно старая, но я ни как не разберусь как сделать input{width: 100%;} в ие7. Торчит кусок справа и все тут. Харисов писал что нужно блоку с инпутом добавить правый margin, но у меня что-то ничего не поменялось..

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:

```
input{
    display:block;
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
input{
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-width:0;
}
```

Comment: Написано же "в ие7". Было бы так просто не спрашивал бы...

Comment: Извините, нет возможности проверить в ИЕ7. Второй вариант проверяли?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробывать обмануть с помощью родительского элемента. По умолчанию, border в осле - что-то порядка 3-ёх пикселей. Если вы не изменяли эту величину, то вот так:

**CSS**

```
.parent_block {
    padding-right: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parent_block input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent_block">
    <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

[Проверяем работу только в осле](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/aq6SR/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать одноразовый expression в CSS и подключать его только для ИЕ7 через условный комментарий. Выглядеть это будет вот так:

```
input {
    z-index: expression( 
      runtimeStyle.zIndex = 1,
      runtimeStyle.width = parentNode.offsetWidth - 4 + 'px');
}
```

Это позволит выставить нужную ширину полю и не добавлять дополнительные обвертки и прочие шаманства. Условие выполняется только 1 раз и не будет нагружать систему.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/aq6SR/5/)

Если же по каким-то принципиальным соображениям противники expression - то у [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis) хороший вариант с padding.